# Separate react native app from reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lerna, react-native-web

I used [react native web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) with my react native app

Can I have same react native and react native web code in the same place?

currently, my mobile code in src\mobile as you can see here:
https://github.com/amorenew/LifeMaster/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this library very helpful

https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start/tree/react-16

It has a template which builds your repo for web, mobile, desktop electron in just one simple command

```
react-native init yourProjectName --template re-start
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `react-native-web` uses babel to change your import statements to use components from `react-native-web` when compiling for web.

When you compile your project for mobile, the components are imported from `react-native` like normal.

Comment: you didn't how could I have a mono repo

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. A `react-native-web` project uses the same code to compile for mobile and web. It is a mono repo by default. I found this example project that may help. https://github.com/kauffecup/react-native-web-hello-world